# Using read() directly into a C++ std:vector

Tags: c++, sockets, vector, buffer

I'm wrapping up user space linux socket functionality in some C++ for an embedded system (yes, this is probably reinventing the wheel again).

I want to offer a read and write implementation using a vector.

Doing the write is pretty easy, I can just pass `&myvec[0]` and avoid unnecessary copying. I'd like to do the same and read directly into a vector, rather than reading into a char buffer then copying all that into a newly created vector.

Now, I know how much data I want to read, and I can allocate appropriately (`vec.reserve()`). I can also read into `&myvec[0]`, though this is probably a VERY BAD IDEA. Obviously doing this doesn't allow myvec.size to return anything sensible. Is there any way of doing this that:

1. Doesn't completely feel yucky from a safety/C++ perspective
2. Doesn't involve two copies of the data block - once from kernel to user space and once from a C `char *` style buffer into a C++ vector.

Comment: A vector of chars (well, bytes)!

Comment: You probably want to use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` for bytes.

Comment: @tzaman: `read` takes a `char*`, so however you dress it up, if you want guaranteed-unsigned data you have to either convert or re-interpret at some point. On a non-2's-complement system with a signed char, re-interpreting (by using a `vector<unsigned char>`) would be disastrous. On more sensible systems it's just a question of whether you want to cast the pointer, or implicitly convert the values as you get them out of the vector.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`. This will set the vector's size correctly -- and after that, `&myvec[0]` is, as usual, guaranteed to point to a continguous block of memory.

Edit: Using `&myvec[0]` as a pointer to the underlying array for both reading and writing is safe and guaranteed to work by the C++ standard. Here's what Herb Sutter [has to say](http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/):

> So why do people continually ask whether the elements of a std::vector (or std::array) are stored contiguously? The most likely reason is that they want to know if they can cough up pointers to the internals to share the data, either to read or to write, with other code that deals in C arrays. That’s a valid use, and one important enough to guarantee in the standard.

Comment: That's peachy, and certainly answers point 2 (tested and works too, thanks! :-) ), but is this approach safe and clean, or is there any other way? I can't help but feel that passing the address of the vectors contiguous memory block to write into seems dangerous?

Comment: @Joe: In the words of Herb Sutter: "Cringe not" -- it's perfectly safe. See my edit above and the link to Herb Sutter's blog entry.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :-) As ever stackoverflow.com delivers!

Comment: I am a person from the future having almost exactly the same problem.  I was considering ".resize(...)", but it initializes the values (which is bad for performance).  Seems like it's still the best option though.  +1.

Comment: @MartinB Is there any other modern sollution? Maybe using C++14, C++17 (or either maybe C++20) features?

Comment: It's useful to be able to do this. I saw a benchmark of all the different ways of doing file I/O in C++ (read/write, fread/fwrite, and then the more c plus plusy ways). The fastest was fread/fwrite. Not being cut off from those old C functions is useful!

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add a short clarification, because the answer was already given. resize() with argument greater than current size will add elements to the collection and default - initialize them. If You create

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
```

and then resize

```
v.resize(someSize);
```

All unsigned chars will get initialized to 0. Btw You can do the same with a constructor

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v(someSize);
```

So theoretically it may be a little bit slower than a raw array, but if the alternative is to copy the array anyway, it's better.

Reserve only prepares the memory, so that there is no reallocation needed, if new elements are added to the collection, but You can't access that memory.

You have to get an information about the number of element written to Your vector. The vector won't know anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a POD struct, call `resize` rather than `reserve`. You can define an empty default constructor if you really don't want the data zeroed out before you fill the vector.

It's somewhat low level, but the semantics of construction of POD structs is purposely murky. If `memmove` is allowed to copy-construct them, I don't see why a socket-read shouldn't.

**EDIT:** ah, bytes, not a struct. Well, you can use the same trick, and define a struct with just a `char` and a default constructor which neglects to initialize it… if I'm guessing correctly that you care, and that's why you wanted to call `reserve` instead of `resize` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the vector to reflect the amount of data read, call `resize()` twice. Once before the read, to give yourself space to read into. Once again after the read, to set the size of the vector to the number of bytes actually read. `reserve()` is no good, since calling reserve doesn't give you permission to access the memory allocated for the capacity.

The first `resize()` will zero the elements of the vector, but this is unlikely to create much of a performance overhead. If it does then you could try Potatoswatter's suggestion, or you could give up on the size of the vector reflecting the size of the data read, and instead just `resize()` it once, then re-use it exactly as you would an allocated buffer in C.

Performance-wise, if you're reading from a socket in user mode, most likely you can easily handle data as fast as it comes in. Maybe not if you're connecting to another machine on a gigabit LAN, or if your machine is frequently running 100% CPU or 100% memory bandwidth. A bit of extra copying or memsetting is no big deal if you are eventually going to block on a `read` call anyway.

Like you, I'd want to avoid the extra copy in user-space, but not for performance reasons, just because if I don't do it, I don't have to write the code for it...

Comment: Normally I wouldn't care about the extra copy really, but I'm on a real time system with low resources. The whole read/write process is non-blocking. Of course, this obviously leads to questions about STL containers in a real time system vs static memory allocation etc....