# How to get a non-nullptr from an empty container?

Tags: c++, pointers

I use a C API which takes a pointer to an array. This array can be empty.

The API works as expected with pointers when they are declared with :

`T *ptr = new T[size];`

but I would like to use the underlying pointer of `C++` container instead (with `.data()`), to avoid to be in charge of deallocation.

So, I declare my container like this :

`std::vector<T> vec(size);`

Unfortunately, when `size` is `0`, `ptr` is not `nullptr` and `vec.data()` is `nullptr`,
therefore, the API behaves differently than before.

Is there a way to get a non-nullptr from an empty container ?

Comment: what pointer to you want to get from the container when there is no `data` ?

Comment: It's an implementation detail. You cannot change the behaviour of `data()` on `empty` vector unless you modify your stdlib implementation yourself.

Comment: Don't you pass also `size`? so how `nullptr` is problematic

Comment: @Jarod42 You pass size to [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) too, and yet passing nullptr is UB.

Comment: for reference (wrong answer deleted): its not sufficient to `reserve`, because even with reserved memory `data` might return `nullptr`

Comment: Related, but not yet a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25419851/417197

Comment: `T* ptr = v.data(); if (ptr == nullptr) { static char dummy; ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&dummy); }`

Comment: @Eljay probably not useful to use a static variable instead of something that don't change like in  Hans Olsson's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to avoid to be in charge of deallocation.

`std::unique_ptr` might be more adapted than `std::vector` in your case:

```
std::unique_ptr<T[]> ptr = std::make_unique<T[]>(size);
```

but `size` is not saved/retrievable with that smart pointer...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421819/18316497) was giving the same advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual C++ raises warning [C4200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-levels-2-and-4-c4200?view=msvc-170) and error C2440 for this code..

Comment: No warnings [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vvW4cxq4x)...

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard one, but you could try something like the following instead of vec.data() - even if horrible and you should see if the C-interface can be changed:

```
vec.empty() ? reinterpret_cast<T*>(0xdeadbeef) : vec.data()
```

That is a non-null ptr, that cannot be de-referenced - so the C-code may crash if it actually tries to de-reference it.

As noted in comments you can use `sizeof(T)` instead of `0xdeadbeef`; which is properly aligned, but the pointer is still likely invalid.

Comment: Dereferencing an invalid pointer is not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But **never rely** on a program that has UB. The program **may** just crash."*

Comment: I'd rather go with `(T *)sizeof(T)`. This will not collide with anything, and is properly aligned.

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, meant it as a warning that it is likely to crash; not as a hard guarantee.

Comment: You need to add a static_cast to uintptr_t to avoid warning C4312 with Visual C++ : reinterpret_cast<T*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(0xdeadbeef)). This is a little bit annoying since uintptr_t is marked "optional" in cstddef.

Comment: Why not directly return the adress of the container ? &vec

Comment: The goal is to have a pointer is fairly easy to notice, and unlikely to work.